# How to implement "--print-media-type" with c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I am currently using wkhtmltopdf with c# to download my webpage as PDF format. However, I want the generated PDF shown to be using "print.css".

Additional Details:
I am using microsoft visual studio 2010.

This is my code:

```
protected void ImageButton2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    string args = string.Format("\"{0}\" - ", Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Server.MapPath("~/wkhtmltoPDF/") + "wkhtmltopdf.exe", args)
    {
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true
    };

    var proc = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };
    proc.Start();

    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename=StaffDetails.pdf", Guid.NewGuid()));
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf"); string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    byte[] buffer = proc.StandardOutput.CurrentEncoding.GetBytes(output);
    proc.Close();
    Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add it as an argument. Try something like

```
string args = string.Format("--print-media-type \"{0}\" - ", Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
```